# UnwindToList with multiple NSMutableArrays

Tags: objective-c

Ok so I have 7 NSMutableArrays and they are connected to a tableview
the first table-view tells the second table-view which one to load,
and it loads fine, but each one I want to be able to add a item/cell, but 
I could only get it to load for one of my views.
Here is my NSMutableArrays list of items and properties.

Properties:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *Movies;

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *Tv_Shows;

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *Resturuants;

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *Video_Games;

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *Concert_Venues;

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *Foods;

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *Recipes
```

NSMutableArray items

```
 _Movies = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Avatar", @"Kung Fu Panda", @"The Matrix", nil];
_Tv_Shows = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Reguluar Show", @"Kung Fu Panda", @"Avatar The last Airbender", nil];
_Resturuants = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Outback Steakhouse", @"Golden Corral", @"Wendy's", nil];
_Video_Games = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"black Ops", @"Call Of Duty", @"Modern Warfare", nil];
_Foods = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Baked Bread", @"Pasta", @"Italian Meatballs", nil];
_Recipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chocolate Cookies", @"Brownies", @"Peanutbutter Fudge", nil];
_Concert_Venues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Pheonix", @"Buckeye", @"Maricopa", nil];
```

Unwind To List Method it only loads for the first item.

```
- (IBAction)unwindToTableViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender {

    AddViewController *addViewController = (AddViewController *)sender.sourceViewController;
    NSString *text = addViewController.textField.text;

    //if NOT blank and NOT whitespace
    if (![text length] == 0 && ![[text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length] == 0) {

        //Add it to the top of the data source.
        [_Movies insertObject:text atIndex:0];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

        //Insert it into the tableview
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
//Add it to the top of the data source.

        [_Movies insertObject:text atIndex:0];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

As you can see only _movies is being loaded, you have to do the same for _TvShows,Restaurants, etc... with increasing values (as in not 0). For example

```css
[_Restaruants insertObject:text atIndex:1];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];

//you may have to keep inSection:0, try it with 1 anyway
```

Comment: yeah I loled when I saw it, would you mind upvoting my answer? I get more reputation from it

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

```
- (IBAction)unwindToTableViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender {

AddViewController *addViewController = (AddViewController *)sender.sourceViewController;
NSString *text = addViewController.textField.text;

//if NOT blank and NOT whitespace
if (![text length] == 0 && ![[text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length] == 0) {

    //Add it to the top of the data source.
    [_Movies insertObject:text atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    //Insert it into the tableview
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

}
Add Items under the _Movies
like so

```
[_Movies insertObject:text atIndex:0];
```

then add new ones